# How to create an If statement that will change the alpha of a label depending on the number of a variable I have created?

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement

I have set a label's alpha to 0 in `viewDidLoad`:

I want the label's alpha to change to 1 once the variable 'count' has reached 8.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        messageFour.alpha = 0

} 

 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if Count == 8 {
        self.label.alpha = 1
    }
}
```

The count works fine, but when it reaches 8 the label is not showing!

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your condition is fine. Perhaps the issue is somewhere else in your code? Where do you call that piece of code?

Comment: override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

}

Comment: Check whether did you hided label anywhere.

Comment: post your lable creation code.

Comment: @niX please edit the question and post more context on where and how you call this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only called it once in your `viewDidAppear`. You need to check this condition each time count is incremented.

You can move complete code of your if-else in separate method. Call that method in your `viewDidAppear` as well as when your count values gets incremented.

As @V.Kambhir suugessted you can use property observers `didSet` or `willSet` as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you! I just created a new method and called it in viewDidAppear, and my count methods. Thanks for the swift response no pun intended.

Comment: Glad you could resolve your problem. Did u tried didset as described by V.Kambhir ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use didSet method.

Example:

```
var count = 0 {
    didSet {
        if count == 8 {
            self.label.alpha = 1
        }
    }
}
```

> Apple documentation:
> didSet is called immediately after the new value is stored.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html